# Sending e-mail with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to send e-mails from Google App Engine via a servlet with the following code. application.owner@gmail.com is listed in "Email API authorized senders". I don't get any errors and i don't receive any e-mails. I can see the log message in the log, so I'm pretty sure that the code is executed. Any ideas why I don't receive any e-mails?

```
package com.myapplication;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SendMailServlet extends HttpServlet {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SendMailServlet.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

        try {

            sendMail();

            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Send mail!");

        } catch (AddressException e) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage());
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void sendMail() throws MessagingException {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("application.owner@gmail.com"));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("application.owner@gmail.com"));
        msg.setSubject("The subject");
        msg.setText("The message body");

        Transport.send(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running on appspot.com ("in prod"), or locally? If the latter, it's well documented that mails are *not* actually sent, unless you have your own SMTP installation and use the `--smtp` flag on running `dev_appserver`.

Comment: I'm running in production (on appspot.com, not locally).

Comment: I just compared your code against my working code. It's very much the same so code wise this should work. However i see you log your exceptions with log `Level.FINE`. Please check whether your `webapp/WEB-INF/logging.properties` file is set to `FINE` or `FINEST` to make sure your get all the logs. That or log your exceptions as warning or error, which is what i recommend.

Comment: Good point regarding the log level, thanks. The code is pretty much the example code that I found in the documentation, so I'm a bit surprised that it does not work. Is there any configuration that needs to be done to make it work? or any other conditions that needs to be met?

Comment: @PatrikSalomonsson not really. There are the usual restrictions for the sender's email address but since you send as the owner that shouldn't be an issue. Did the log contain an exception after you changed the logging?

Comment: @konqi The only thing i get in the log id "Send mail!", so I assume that there is no exceptions. Do the user (application.owner) need to be sign-in?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?